# numpy array reshape question

Tags: numpy, image-preprocessing, reshape

Let's say that I have image data with shape $(32, 32, 3)$ and $50000$

1. If I would like to reshape it to $(50000, 3, 32, 32)$ what should I do?

I tried `np.transpose(0, 3, 1, 2)` but it failed.

2. If I would like to print the number $3$ from $(50000, 3, 32, 32)$ what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

If `image` is a numpy object:

```
image = image.reshape((50000,3,32,32))
```

and then print:

```
print(image[:,3,:,:])
```